# USB Hub not recognized by Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: usb

I am trying to connect a USB HUB and at the same time connect a mouse but when I connect it in this way, my mouse stops working, but visually Ubuntu recognizes it and in fact when I connect it directly without the hub it works for me.

Are there any special settings that I am skipping over?

[image]

Comment: Ask Ubuntu is an English Only website.  You need to type questions and answers in English here, even if you have to run it via a translation tool.  I've done a rough translation on your post with Google Translate.

Comment: Did you check your hardware for USB version compatibility? For example, are you trying to plug a USB 3.0 hub into a USB 2.0 port?